# RavenDB complex index

Tags: dictionary, indexing, group-by, ravendb, reduce

While I'm really excited about idea of using RavenDB as OLTP-application storage I'm bit in trouble with Linq/Map-Reduce index implementations.

Here is what I'm trying to do - 
I have documents -

```
Event {
   UserId:  "1",
   Location : "X",
   EventDate : "1/1/2010",
   EventType : "type A"
}
...
Event {
   UserId:  "2",
   Location : "Y",
   EventDate : "1/1/2011",
   EventType : "type B"
}
```

The action query/index supposed to perform is

"Bring me count of different events for specific user in specific date range grouped by location,event"

The result example:

```
Location | Count(EventA) | Count(EventB) 
---------------------------------------
X        | 10            |     2
Y        |  4            |    22
```

I believe this should be straight forward. I'm probably just missing something.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is a typical case for reporting. And that's one thing RavenDB isn't really suited for (http://ravendb.net/docs/server/bundles/index-replication). Your question resembles the structure of a cube in SQL Server Analysis Services.

[image]

The problem in this case is the date range. If the ranges are fixed, say I want to know it for each month, you could do this in an index, but if the ranges are ad hoc, then I believe this will not be possible in Raven by using an index and presumably not even a query because you would have to do the grouping client side and thus would have to retrieve a large amount of documents (far more than Raven's default 128).

But in case someone is searching for a multiple group by example in an index where we omit the date range then following index implementation where results are grouped by userid, location and event type could be a solution:

```
public class Index : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Index.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string EventType { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

    public Index()
    {
        Map = events => from e in events
                        select new Result
                        {
                            UserId = e.UserId,
                            Location = e.Location,
                            EventType = e.EventType,
                            Count = 1
                        };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by new { result.UserId, result.Location, result.EventType }
                                into g
                                select new Result
                                {
                                    UserId = g.Key.UserId,
                                    Location = g.Key.Location,
                                    EventType = g.Key.EventType,
                                    Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count)
                                };
    }
}
```

This will give you this result

```
UserId   | Location | EventType     | Count
-------------------------------------------
1        | X        | A             |     2
1        | X        | B             |     4
1        | Y        | A             |    22
1        | Y        | B             |     6
2        | X        | A             |     7
2        | X        | B             |     3
2        | Y        | A             |     9
2        | Y        | B             |    16
```

You can then query that index and do additional grouping on the results of the query.

Comment: Good answer.  You hit on the core of the problem - you can't have an arbitrary date range.  If you wanted them grouped per day, per week, per month, etc.  then you can.  It might be possible to use multiple indexes and intersect the results to make it feel more arbitrary. I have been planning to get to that for awhile now...